# Is ArcGIS Pro result for interpolation correct?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, interpolation

I did a Diffusion Interpolation with barriers (uses kernel). My real maximum value for Turbidity is 80, but in interpolation raster maximum value is only 34.82.

Could it be considered correct for the interpolation?

Interpolation cell value:
[image]

The real value of a point nearby (Turb = 80):
[image]

Maximum value is only 34.82 for the whole interpolation:

[image]

Comment: Kernel interpolation is not precise, as opposite to triangulation.

Comment: Is not exact interpolation method.